# An internal error occurred during: "Generating Docker Image..."

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

My Integration project runs fine when I export and run in micro integrator. I am trying to generate a docker image from the composite exporter. But I am getting the error given below.

An internal error occurred during: "Generating Docker Image..."

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Named
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:73)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:63)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.docker.distribution.util.DockerImageGenerator.<init>(DockerImageGenerator.java:64)
    at org.wso2.integrationstudio.docker.distribution.job.GenerateDockerImageJob.run(GenerateDockerImageJob.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.inject.Named cannot be found by org.wso2.integrationstudio.docker.distribution_8.1.0.202212190508
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 10 more
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to build on Java 11 or a higher version. AFAIK `javax` packages were deprecated and removed from JDK 11 onward. Hence you can try downgrading your Java version to JDK 8 or else try adding `javax.inject` as a external dependency to the pom.xml.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```